# How to eliminate the shadow in iOS

Tags: ios, cglayer

I want to create a ImageView Object , But ，when I use contentRect property to create , the result have any shadow , help me .

Look this code :

```
CALayer *blueLayer = [CALayer layer];
blueLayer.frame = CGRectMake(50.0f, 50.0f, 100.0f, 200.0f);
blueLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"vclrs_me_wodeshoucang"] ;
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage ;
blueLayer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)imageRef ;
blueLayer.contentsGravity =  kCAGravityCenter ;
blueLayer.contentsRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 2, 2) ;
blueLayer.contentsScale = image.scale ;
[self.layerView.layer addSublayer:blueLayer];
```

And , Please read the result (picture) :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410866-contentsrect?language=objc

**According to above documentation**

Defaults to the unit rectangle (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0).

If pixels outside the unit rectangle are requested, **the edge pixels of the contents image will be extended outwards.**

If an empty rectangle is provided, the results are undefined.

So according to it it will give output like this

[image]

Comment: If you dont mind ,Can you send me your project at modijecky@gmail.com so I can see it properly what problem you r facing?

Comment: Has been sent, please check . Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve means actual output ?

Comment: This is not what I want 。 if contentRect is not empty , How to eliminate the shadow ？

Comment: @user5465320 but you can not give contentrect greater than (0,0,1,1) if you give then  the edge pixels of the contents image will be extended outwards.

Comment: Well, can only be the case

Comment: @user5465320 yeah, officail documentation says so we cant do anything

Answer (score 0):

Try set self.layerView.clipsToBounds = YES